# How to safe stop a service on android and exit the process

Tags: android, service

I want to implement a background service like.***When the network available,start the service,otherwise,stop it include the process***.(this app without activity).Here is how I implement it.

1.register a static boardcastReceiver.Listener the following boardcast

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

2.inside the **onReceive** method.do the action to start or stop service component.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    Intent service = new Intent(context,MonitorService.class);
    boolean running = isMyServiceRunning(context);
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if (!running){
            Log.i(TAG,"Network avaliable, start Service ");
            context.startService(service);
        }
    } else {
        if (running){
            Log.i(TAG,"Network unavaliable, stop Service ");
            context.stopService(service);
        }
    }
}
```

3.What I found was really interesting.First we install the application.Now it was not running.Then I open the WiFi.The logcat output somethings and now I'm pretty sure the service is running.I have a separate thread create inside the service.when I disable the WiFi.The service callback method onDestory was invoked.Here I will destroy the thread which I created previously to release resource etc..

Everything looks work properly.Now the service component stop,without the activity.**but the process still alive !!** I simply call **android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())** inside the onDestory .but it doesn't make any sense.

4.Inside the service: if the service has been killed by the system,it should be auto restart. If i stop by myself, it should not.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onStartCommand " + flags);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Any help will be a appropriate. have a good day.:D

Add more =======================================================

I read the android developer document about processes and threads.found this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

**Empty process**
A process that doesn't hold any active application components. The only reason to keep this kind of process alive is for caching purposes, to improve startup time the next time a component needs to run in it. The system often kills these processes in order to balance overall system resources between process caches and the underlying kernel caches.

Anyway I know when I stop the service, the process become empty process,less memory consume and maybe not active. But I still want to kill it.

Comment: Did you override the onDestroy() method in your service class?

Comment: The process can be alive because of either the service or an activity. Is there a way you can see which one is it?

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin       yes.on the onDestory() method i destory a thread which i create pervious.i found the following on

Comment: @Merlevede i just instantiate on service component.the only alive component maybe was the static boardcastreceiver.but it's make no scene.the boardcastreceive lifecycle only exist onReceive method.right ?